# How to configure diagnostic settings for APIM for all api using Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have created a APIM Service, LogAnalyticWorkSpace and AppInsight resource using Bicep. Now I want add diagnostic settings to All API using bicep. I am able to do it at api level, but how do I do it at "ALL API" using bicep.

The code I have used to configure at API level

```
 resource apiManagementServiceName_api_name 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: apiManagementServiceName_resource
  name: api_name
  properties: {
    displayName: api_name
    apiRevision: '1'
    subscriptionRequired: true
    path: api_name
    protocols: [
      'https'
    ] 
  }
}

resource apiManagementAPIAppInsights 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics@2021-08-01'={
  name:'appInsights'
  parent:apiManagementServiceName_api_name
  properties:{
    loggerId:loggerid
    alwaysLog:'allErrors'
    verbosity:'error'
  }
}
```

I want to configure a setting which on UI is shown here

[Azure APIM Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbBAk.png)

Comment: After some more research I found a solution for this .

Comment: I am currently trying to configure a diagnostic setting on API Level. As you mentioned you had that in the beginning with your provided Code. However, the parent has to by of type 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service' instead of 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis'. Do you have a solution for that? I can only add a diagnostic setting for the whole API but want to specify it on API level

Answer (score 2):

We need to use service/loggers and service/diagnostics for this

```
resource apiManagementLogging 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/loggers@2021-08-01'={
  name:'${apiManagementServiceName}/${appInsightName}'
  properties:{
    loggerType:'applicationInsights'
    description:'Logger resources for APIM'
    credentials:{
      instrumentationKey:instrumentationKey   
    }
  }
}
resource apiManagemementDiagnostics 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/diagnostics@2021-08-01'={
  name:'applicationinsights'
  parent:apiManagementServiceName_resource
  properties:{
    loggerId:apiManagementLogging.id
    alwaysLog:'allErrors'

  }
  dependsOn:[apiManagementLogging]
}
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, for me it is opposite: `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/diagnostics` does not work, but `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics` does.